# How to upgrade PostgreSQL minor releases without a dump/restore?

Tags: postgresql

Our production server is running PostgreSQL v8.2.3 on CentOS5.2.  We're planning to upgrade to the latest version in 8.2 series, that is [v8.2.20](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-8-2-20.html).  Also, in future, we've planned to upgrade to the most recent minor release as soon as possible (as and when released by PostgreSQL).

Initially, we've installed v8.2.3 from source.  PostgreSQL is installed in */usr/local/pgsql/* and data directory is available in */usr/local/pgsql/data*

PostgreSQL [Versioning policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning) says:

> Upgrading to a minor release does not
>   require a dump and restore; merely
>   stop the database server, install the
>   updated binaries, and restart the
>   server.

Now, without a dump/restore, what are the recommended ways/steps involved in upgrading PostgreSQL to latest version for minor releases?

**EDIT:** Well, I should have asked my question this way.  Since the doc says `install the updated binaries`, my question is whether the latest version can be installed as-is. Will my data directory */usr/local/pgsql/data/* be disturbed in any way? Or should this data directory be moved temporarily until the latest installation  is completed.  In addition,  iss there anything, as an admin, I need to take care, like, taking a backup of */usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf*, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are doing a minor version upgrade, nothing will or should touch your data directory.  If you are using binary packages, just run whatever upgrade procedure they provide (apt/yum upgrade, etc.).  If building from source, just do `make install` over the old files and then restart the server (`pg_ctl restart` or whatever you're using).

The documentation could perhaps be amended to say that you could even install the new binaries before restarting the server.